# How to transform a nullable variable as an interface in typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

Problem happened when I developing a vue3.x typescript project. The vue file like this:

```
<template>
    <Comp ref="compRef" />
</template>
<script lang="ts" setup>
    import {ref} from "vue";
    import Comp from "@/components/Comp";

    // This var'value initial with null, but will be filled with reference named "compRef".
    const compRef = ref(null);

    // 1. Direct call
    // compRef.value.Show();  // Rise error "Object is possibly 'null'."

    // 2. Transform as a component module
    // (compRef.value as Comp).Show();  // Rise error "'Comp' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Comp'?"
    
    // 3. Transform as a interface
    // interface IComp { Show: ()=>void; }
    // (compRef.value as IComp).Show();  // Rise error "Conversion of type 'null' to type 'IComp' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first."

    (compRef.value as any).Show();
</script>
```

Transform it as any type can solve this problem, but I do want to transform it into a specific type or interface. Is there any way to transform a nullable variable as an interface in typescript?

Comment: compRef?.value?.Show()

Comment: @BeSterDevelopment The statement will rise error "Property 'Show' does not exist on type 'never'".

Comment: @BeSterDevelopment You answer inspired me to check the 'ref' method. The 'ref' method provides a <T> value whitch the value property will be transformed to!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just solved this problem!

```
const compRef = ref<IComp | null>(null);
compRef.value?.Show();
```